# Operation on bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have the following s-box

```
const unsigned char sbox[16][16] = {
  {0x5, 0xC, 0x1, 0x0, 0x2, 0xE, 0x9, 0x8, 0xF, 0xD, 0x3, 0xB, 0x7, 0xA, 0x4, 0x6},
  {0xF, 0x4, 0x3, 0xA, 0x8, 0xD, 0x6, 0x2, 0x5, 0xE, 0x1, 0x7, 0xB, 0x0, 0xC, 0x9},
  {0x6, 0x7, 0xD, 0x2, 0x0, 0x3, 0xF, 0xA, 0x9, 0x1, 0xE, 0x4, 0xC, 0x8, 0xB, 0x5},
  {0x8, 0xD, 0x7, 0x9, 0xF, 0x4, 0x0, 0x5, 0x2, 0xC, 0xB, 0x3, 0x1, 0x6, 0xE, 0xA},
  {0x4, 0xF, 0x0, 0x1, 0xD, 0x8, 0x7, 0xE, 0xC, 0x2, 0xA, 0x6, 0x9, 0x3, 0x5, 0xB},
  {0x9, 0xB, 0xE, 0x8, 0xA, 0x1, 0x5, 0x0, 0x6, 0x3, 0xD, 0xC, 0x4, 0x2, 0x7, 0xF},
  {0xA, 0x1, 0xC, 0xF, 0x9, 0xB, 0x2, 0x6, 0x0, 0x7, 0x4, 0xE, 0xD, 0x5, 0x3, 0x8},
  {0xE, 0x2, 0x9, 0x7, 0xC, 0x5, 0x1, 0x4, 0xD, 0xF, 0x6, 0xA, 0x0, 0xB, 0x8, 0x3},
  {0x7, 0x6, 0x8, 0xE, 0x3, 0x0, 0x4, 0x1, 0xB, 0xA, 0x2, 0xF, 0x5, 0xD, 0x9, 0xC},
  {0x2, 0xE, 0xB, 0x6, 0x5, 0xC, 0xA, 0xF, 0x8, 0x4, 0x7, 0x1, 0x3, 0x9, 0xD, 0x0},
  {0xB, 0x9, 0x2, 0xD, 0x1, 0xA, 0xC, 0x3, 0x7, 0x0, 0x8, 0x5, 0xF, 0xE, 0x6, 0x4},
  {0x0, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x1, 0x2},
  {0x3, 0x0, 0xF, 0xC, 0x7, 0x6, 0xD, 0xB, 0x1, 0x9, 0x5, 0x8, 0x2, 0x4, 0xA, 0xE},
  {0x1, 0xA, 0x5, 0x4, 0xB, 0x9, 0xE, 0x7, 0x3, 0x6, 0xF, 0x2, 0x8, 0xC, 0x0, 0xD},
  {0xD, 0x8, 0x6, 0xB, 0x4, 0xF, 0x3, 0xC, 0xE, 0x5, 0x9, 0x0, 0xA, 0x7, 0x2, 0x1},
  {0xC, 0x5, 0xA, 0x3, 0xE, 0x2, 0xB, 0xD, 0x4, 0x8, 0x0, 0x9, 0x6, 0x1, 0xF, 0x7},
};
```

I need to implement following operation, which is called eLeftQ:

```
eLeft(Q,∗)_l : Q^n → Q^n, a_0,...,a_(n-1) → b_0,...,b_(n-1), b_0 = l ∗ a_0, b_i = b_(i−1) ∗ a_i, i = 1,...,n
```

where operation `*` given by the table above, for example: `0x5 * 0xF = 0xF`, since `sbox[5][15] = 0xF`. `0xF * 0x5 = 0x2`, since `sbox[15][5] = 0x2`.

The problem is this, I have an array of `unsigned char`, each character has a size of 8 bits, but I need to work with 4-bit numbers. So, somehow I need to take first 4 bits of number, calculate product of first 4 bits and some element, then write down in my `char` instead of old 4 bits received new 4 bits and then find product of first 4 bits and last 4 bits of `char`, then take next `char`, pull out first 4 bits and instead of them write down product between last 4 bits of previous `char` and first 4 bits of new `char`.

To make it clearer, consider an example:

According to operation `eLeft` I have an element `L = 0000 1111`, which is `15` in decimal, an for example I have array of chars `{1010 0010, 1000 0101}` (I represented chars as bits). Then I start my algorithm:

- First I pull out bits `1010` (which is `10` in decimal) from first `char` and calculate `sbox[15][10] = 0x0`
- Then write down new bits in my `char` and get `0000 0010`
- Second I pull out bits `0010` (`2`) and calculate according to `eLeft` operation product of `0 * 2`. `Sbox[0][2] = 0x1`. Then write down new bits in my `char` and get `0000 0001`.
- Third I pull out bits `1000` from second `char` and calculate `8 * 1`, where `1` are last 4 bits from first char. `Sbox[8][1] = 0x6`. Then write down new bits in second `char` `0110 0101`.

I used this example just for a better understanding of the algorithm.

My idea was to take 4 bits out of `char`, convert them to `int`, find out the product and write down new bits, but it feels like inefficient, also it turned out to be difficult. Maybe there are better solutions for this problem. If anyone can help, thank you!

Comment: "but it feels like inefficient" well... that doesn't matter. Just implement it and test it. If it doesn't meet your performance requirement, it's time for optimizing.... Then you can ask us for improvements but now... nahh, we ain't gonna write your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to handle a full byte at a time, hence 2 4-bit quartets:

```
/* handle length bytes of data, 2 quartets at a time */
void eLeftQ(unsigned char *data, size_t length, unsigned char l) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // extract the 4 high bits as "first" value and low 4 as "second" value
        unsigned char b1 = data[i] >> 4;
        unsigned char b2 = data[i] & 0x0F;
        b1 = sbox[l][b1];
        b2 = sbox[b1][b2];
        l = b2;
        data[i] = (b1 << 4) | b2;
    }
}
```

If after careful benchmarking you find performance to be inadequate, you could improve this loop's throughput by using a 16x256 precomputed array to compute the bytes directly:

```
void eLeftQ2(unsigned char *data, size_t length, unsigned char l) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        l = data[i] = sbox2[l & 0x0F][data[i]];
    }
}
```